# Rust: I want to get last modified file in a dir

Tags: file, for-loop, rust, metadata

Language: Rust

I have done this already in Python:

```
file = max([f for f in os.scandir("files")], key=lambda x: x.stat().st_mtime).name
```

And now i want to get that in rust too.

I want to get the last modified file in a dir.
this is how i read the dir:

```
let filecheck = fs::read_dir(path)
for path in filecheck {
   
}
```

but i dont know how to use the metadata::modified function to get the list of modified dates and then get the latest one.

I tried to use metadata::modified function and expected to get the result i want. What i got where errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, please describe what errors you encounter while attempting a problem.

Here's a rust snippet that scans the current directory and prints out the most recent file:

```
let last_modified_file = std::fs::read_dir(my_directory_path)
    .expect("Couldn't access local directory")
    .flatten() // Remove failed
    .filter(|f| f.metadata().unwrap().is_file()) // Filter out directories (only consider files)
    .max_by_key(|x| x.metadata().unwrap().modified().unwrap()); // Get the most recently modified file

println!("Most recent file: {:?}", last_modified_file);
```

Notice the several uses of `expect` and `unwrap`. Accessing file metadata is not guaranteed to succeed. The program above assumes it always will succeed for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Thank you very much :)
It works like a charm, but i had to modify it first. Your code gave me the oldest file. I had to modify ` println!("Most recent file: {:?}", entries[0]); ` to ` println!("Most recent file: {:?}", entries[entries.len() -1]);  ` to get the newest file :)

Comment: Note that `Iterator` has a `max_by` and a `max_by_key` as well so you don't actually need to sort if you only need the one last modified file.

Comment: if you're only looking for *files* (not directories), you might want to add a filter, e.g. `.filter(|f| f.metadata().unwrap().is_file())`